# Your Connection is not private. Error. How do I fix it?

Tags: ssl, hsts

Good Afternoon Stack Overflow. I'm relatively new here, I have some question.

I'm experiencing intermittent connection errors on my computer related to SSL certificates. Despite having a valid certificate, the issue persists, and sometimes it reconnects.

The issue is it only happens when I'm using my work network. At home I never experience this. And it also affects my colleagues computers.

How can I troubleshoot and address this problem permanently?

I want to access my own website and I keep getting some connection error.